# CS50 python pset5 refueling

Tags: python, cs50

Here is my solution to CS50 Python pset5 refueling problem. It works fine and passes all my pytest tests. but check50 gives me error
":( correct fuel.py passes all test_fuel checks expected exit code 0, not 1".

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            fraction = input("Fraction: ")
            print(gauge(convert(fraction)))
            break
        except (ValueError,ZeroDivisionError):
            continue


def convert(fraction):
            a,b = fraction.split("/")
            f = int(a) / int(b)
            if int(a) <= int(b) and int(b) != 0 and f <= 1:
                percentage = int(round(f * 100))
                return percentage
            else:
                raise (ZeroDivisionError,ValueError)


def gauge(percentage):
    Z = int(percentage)
    if Z <= 1:
        return "E"
    elif Z >= 99:
        return "F"
    else:
        return f"{Z}%"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are doing well. For the Unit Tests section, the course looks to have all computations, manipulations, etc. performed outside of def main(). Essentially, def main() will only be used to call upon the other function and print the final results. So, def main() should only be

```
def main():

    fraction = input("Fraction: ")
    print(gauge(convert(fraction)))
```

This means you will have to move the while True loop to the def convert().

Also, the raises should be used in your test_fuel.py. It was suggested in the hint section and is linked here. https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/assert.html#assertions-about-expected-exceptions.

Hopefully, this helps. Let me know if you run into other errors or issues.